# What's wrong with my spatial instance?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I am trying to create a geography polygon (a simple box) for SQL Server 2008 spatial types:

```
select geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((18.123632669448853 59.299458646827844, 
18.103247880935669 59.299458646827844, 18.103247880935669 59.304935824311556,
18.123632669448853 59.304935824311556, 18.123632669448853 59.299458646827844))'
, 4326)
```

I keep getting "The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance." and I cannot understand what's wrong with it. If I use LINESTRING to plot each line of the box in the Spatial Results view of the SQL MGM Studio, everything looks fine.

If I put a minus sign in front of all the longitudes it can be created too (but obviously it is not the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, exterior rings of a polygon have to be defined in anti-clockwise order; interior rings clockwise. So swap your second and fourth points over and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you thank you! I did try som swapping. But not that one. :-) Thanks!!